# Debug single role instance with Azure Compute emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, azure, emulation

I'm building an application which will be run on Azure. My Visual Studio solution contains multiple Azure role projects. When debugging locally, I use the Azure compute emulator.

To start debugging, I follow these steps:

1. I right-click on my Azure project and click Set as start up project.
2. I press F5 to start the debugger.

What happens now is that the emulator/vs2010 launches both my web roles and worker roles, even if I'm only interested in debugging a single worker role at the moment. Often when writing some background-processing code in my worker role, I'm interested to step through that code without starting the web role, launch Internet Explorer and so on as well.

Is there a convinient way to make the debugger only launch one of the role instances and not all of them?

I'm thinking of creating a separate project in my solution of type Console Application, where I load the same assemblies as in my worker role and execute the same code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The emulator (similar to Azure itself) works just on the concept of a "Cloud Service".  So when you launch w/ debug, its going to launch whatever is defined in your Cloud Service (.ccproj) project.  This mimics Azure 100% which is why it occur, but I can definitely see where your scenario would be helpful.

Few options, based on your needs.

#### If you need to test azure-specifics (aka it has to run in the emulator)

- Create a second solution file, create a new Cloud service in here, add your project.  *I like this option because the projects/roles themselves remain untouched.*
- What Stuart suggested before me, create a second Cloud Project, set as startup, run that.
- Similar to above, create a second project, but don't worry about startup.  You can right click on any project, go to Debug and select **start w/ debugging** and achieve what F5 does without binding F5 to this solution

#### If you dont need to test azure-specifics (ie you are just testing the role)

- Right click on the role's project, Debug, **Start with Debugging** *This way the whole solution remains intact and you are just testing the logic*

Comment: But if you delete a role temporarily, you'll lose all its config settings, local storage settings, declared endpoints, etc. It might be better to comment things out in `ServiceDefinition.csdef` and `ServiceConfiguration.cscfg` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I shoulda tried that one before recommending.  I removed it from my list, as the other suggestions are more appropriate to his needs anyways.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do this by:

- create a new Azure Cloud Project within your solution
- add just the one worker role to that cloud project
- set that cloud project as your startup project

This will single out just the worker you are interested in

Answer (score -3):

An easier solution would be to open the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file, and set the "Instances > Count" property to "0", for all the roles that you don't want running (this only works in the compute-emulator, and NOT on the azure cloud).

That way, you keep your solution intact and your configurations safe, while just omitting them from the compute-emulator during run-time.

Comment: This didn't actually work for me - it fails with "Instance count of 0 is not supported in deployments to Windows Azure"